# Connecting two wireless routers with ethernet - will the secondary router transmit wirelessly?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I have two wireless routers.
The primary router is a Thomson TG784 is wireless modem router.
The second wireless router is a TP-Link TD W8950ND.

If I connect the primary router to the secondary router with an ethernet cable, will the second transmit wireless internet automatically?

I've just moved to a new office. We need both ethernet and wireless.
The office has an small ethernet network installed. However, in order to use it the primary modem wireless router needs to be in the telecoms box outside the office in the hallway. I believe this will affect the quality of the wireless in the office quite a bit.

I was hoping to put the primary modem in the telecoms panel (outside in the hall) and connect it to the ethernet outputs (in the office), which would provide ethernet internet in the office. If I could use that ethernet to plug into the second router it could then boost the wireless signal within the office. 
The primary modem needs to be the one connecting to the internet as it is from the ISP.

Thanks for any wisdom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not do so automatically. You will need to configure the new WiFi router to broadcast a network that you can connect to.

Check the manual for how to access the router's configuration page (it should be something like 192.168.0.1), then perform the configuration. You'll want to use WPA or WPA2 encryption, as WEP is broken.